# how to set icon in edittext in android in API level 15 or 16

Tags: android

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hint="Cursor Color changed"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"/>
```

This code work but for API level 17

Comment: Make a custom layout containing icon and edittext and than include that in your main layout..it will work for all APIs :)

Comment: drawableLeft is added from android api level 1. why it didnt work

Comment: thanks - developer